# Stop IPTables on Reboot

Tags: iptables

I'm looking to stop iptables when the server reboots. I know this is not practical but I have an issue that I'm trying to work out with iptables so for right now I need it to stop on reboot. Right now iptables starts so just looking for an automatic way to stop that service on reboot. Thanks everyone!

Comment: what do you mean with "stop iptables when the server reboots"? Do you mean you want to remove the rules during shutdown? iptables rules aren't persistent; they need to be set up every boot!

Comment: I want to stop the service each time the server reboots.

Comment: three things a) iptables is not a service b) everything that *is* a service needs to restart when the server reboots, I mean, the definition of "reboot" is that everything stops and is started again c) it's really not clear what you *need*. Please explain what you want to happen – not what you think needs to be done to achieve that.

Comment: The name of the service responsible for reloading the iptables rules on reboot will vary by distribution, and you haven't indicated which distribution you're using. Also, have you installed any firewall management packages like `firewalld` or `ufw`, or any third-party anti-malware software (whose firewall functionality is usually just a GUI front-end to iptables)?

Comment: I have a simple command I run on the shell when the server boots. It's:

sudo service iptables stop

That is the command I run when the server reboots. I need to run that command automatically on reboot so that the service stops.

Answer (score 0):

In the comments, you said:

```
 sudo service iptables stop
```

This tells us that the iptables settings are managed by a service named `iptables`: not `iptables-restore`, not `firewalld` nor `ufw`.

> That is the command I run when the server reboots. I need to run that command automatically on reboot so that the service stops.

**No, you're mistaken.** You need to run either:

- `sudo systemctl disable iptables` (if your system uses `systemd`)
- or `sudo chkconfig iptables off` (for systems with no `systemd`).

These commands should prevent the `iptables` from starting at boot, **so there will be nothing that needs to be stopped in the first place.**

To undo the effect, use `sudo systemctl enable iptables` or `sudo chkconfig iptables on`, respectively. These commands will make `iptables` start again at next and subsequent reboots.

If you are using `systemd` and some other service is configured to *need* `iptables`, then you may have to use `sudo systemctl mask iptables` to absolutely prevent it from starting, even at the cost of that other service failing to start. To undo that, `sudo systemctl unmask iptables`.

Answer (score 0):

As per comments, there is no "start" or "stop". If the kernel is running, iptables is available (but you could blacklist the module, but that is not the answer to whatever question the OP is really asking).

Disabling the loading of rules is probably not the right way to solve the problem either. The right way to fix the problem is to change the rules to something appropriate (even if that means no active rules) and set that as the default configuration. That way if you ever do need functionality which depends on iptables (e.g. docker) then you can use that functionality.

Since we don't know what distribution this is, we can't tell you how to do that. It is likely that the configuration is stored somewhere in /etc in a file with "iptables" in the name.

Comment: If I wanted an answer that tells me I shouldn't do it that way then I would have asked differently. It was a simple question about how to run it automatically and I should have started with Google because I found it within a few seconds. You might want to figure out how to answer a simple question without interjecting your own thoughts of what might be wrong or right. Good day to you sir....